# String literals to number at compile time

Tags: c++, enums, macros, constexpr

I'm working hard in order to translate many macros into (scoped, type-safe) const values. My goal is to use them, if necessary, with `if constexpr`.

For now I've managed to have satisfactory results with some macros using stringify macros and template functions:

```
#define STRINGIFY(X) #X
#define TO_STRING(X) STRINGIFY(X)
```

The macros above have a *surprising* different behaviour depending on the given parameter:

```
std::cout << TO_STRING(_DEBUG) << '\n';
```

Shows `_DEBUG` if (and only if) the macro `_DEBUG` **is NOT defined**, but if defined it shows the macro value (or an empty string if defined but without value).

Anyway, the macro result would always be a [text literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) so I'm using a `constexpr` function to check the result:

```
template <int SIZE>
constexpr bool b(const char (&definition)[SIZE])
{
    return definition[0] != '_';
}
```

And now combining `STRINGIFY` and `b`, it is possible to create enumerations and use them in `if constexpr` (instead of using `#ifdef` chains):

```
enum operating_system : bool
{
    iOS     = b(TO_STRING(__APPLE__)),
    Windows = b(TO_STRING(__MINGW32__)),
    Linux   = b(TO_STRING(__linux__)),
};

int main()
{
    if constexpr (operating_system::Windows)
    {
        // Specific Windows stuff.
    }
    else if constexpr (operating_system::iOS)
    {
        // Specific iOS stuff.
    }

    // Platform-independent sutff.

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not happy using a helper function to translate the literals to bool values (`b` function) but isn't a big deal. The real problem is that it relies on detecting the starting underscore (`_`) in order to detect the non-existent macros. So an existing macro with a value starting with underscore would be a false positive. Also, the real value of the macro is lost, let's see an example:

```
#define _DEBUG 0
#define DRIVERS _09072007

template <int SIZE>
constexpr int i(const char (&definition)[SIZE])
{
    return definition[0] != '_'; // what shall I put here?...
}

enum stuff : int
{
    cpp_version     = i(TO_STRING(__cplusplus)),
    debug_enabled   = i(TO_STRING(_DEBUG)),
    drivers_version = i(TO_STRING(DRIVERS)),
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "C++ version: "     << stuff::cpp_version << '\n'
              << "Debug mode: "      << stuff::debug_enabled << '\n'
              << "Drivers version: " << stuff::drivers_version << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The code above shows:

> ```
> C++ version: 1
> Debug mode: 1
> Divers version: 0
> ```

Expected, but not satisfactory. I need a way to translate those string literals to the real value (at compile time) and a workaround of the naive approach of the "*it exists if not starts with underscore*" problem that the `DRIVERS` macro is showing (maybe ignoring non numeric values until a numeric value is found?).

I've tried with recursive approach but indexing a string literal is not a constant expression:

```
constexpr int power10(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;

    return 10 * power10(n - 1);
}

template <int SIZE>
constexpr int v(const char (&definition)[SIZE], int INDEX)
{
    // error: 'definition' is not a constant expression
    constexpr char c = definition[INDEX];


    if (INDEX >= 0)
    {
        if constexpr (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        {
            return v(definition, INDEX - 1) + (power10(SIZE - INDEX - 2) * (c - '0'));
        }
        else
        {
            return 0 + v(definition, INDEX - 1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

template <int SIZE>
constexpr int f(const char (&definition)[SIZE])
{
    return v(definition, SIZE - 2);
}

enum operating_system : bool
{
    // error: enumerator value for 'iOS' is not an integer constant
    iOS     = f(TO_STRING(__APPLE__)),
    // error: enumerator value for 'Windows' is not an integer constant
    Windows = f(TO_STRING(__MINGW32__)),
    // error: enumerator value for 'Linux' is not an integer constant
    Linux   = f(TO_STRING(__linux__)),
};
```

Comment: What about #if and #ifdef directives, without gratuitous strings?

Comment: I want to avoid using macros as much as I can. And [I'm not the only one](http://blog.tartanllama.xyz/c++/2016/12/12/if-constexpr/).

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QozHt6gWQO7bwbth)?

Comment: @W.F. I understand that `Debug mode` should be `0` and `Driver version` probably `09072007`

Comment: @llonesmiz well I'm not sure what is the OP expected result but pointing that he can easily use `for` loop inside the constexpr function and the result is still constexpr (as long as c++14 is available, and as `if constexpr` is in a game I assume it is)

Comment: @W.F. let me try with a `for` loop, maybe you're right!

Comment: @W.F. [it Works with a `for` loop](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/dRSJORwUFc2H2Nw1) like a charm! Thank you! Would you be so kind to write an answer in order to accept it?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Very interesting question and nice solution but note that if you had a macro that is not defined and contains a number in its name your approach would fail.

Comment: @llonesmiz I didn't realized until you mentioned it. It's a very annoying problem indeed. It will produce false positives with `__WIN32`!!

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster As you observed `STRINGIFY(MACRO)` is `"MACRO"` only when `MACRO` is undefined but `#MACRO` is always `"MACRO"`. You can possibly use that to decide if a macro is defined or not. [This approach](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RxIcksSB3kHt4LMt) is probably not suitable for you (introduces Boost dependencies and complexity) but it shows that it is possible to do what you want.